# Maya import standalone

Tags: python, maya

I would like to run `maya` module code in an external editor (like VSCode) by NOT using `mayapy.exe`. Reason is that I am running a lot of other code as well, so cutting out the maya bit just to throw it in `mayapy.exe` is not really a great solution for me.

Therefore I need to create a maya standalone like this:

```
from maya import standalone
standalone.initialize()
```

My problem is that `from maya import standalone` obviously doesn't exist in VSCode. So I add this line at the top for that:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\Python\Lib\site-packages\maya')
from maya import standalone
standalone.initialize()
```

But I am still getting this error:
`ImportError: cannot import name standalone`

Any idea how I can get `standalone` working from outside Maya?

Comment: As far as I know, you HAVE to run `standalone` in `mayapy`. If you find otherwise, please post back here -- I would definitely be interested in hearing more about that :)

Comment: mayapy is specifically compiled for maya. If you need to run maya cmds and other functionality, then simply update the site-packages in your maya installation. I'm not convinced vanilla Python will work with maya packages. If your issue is getting VSCode to recognize the mayapy interpretor, I'm pretty sure you can find a way on the internet.